# Popup menu in MFC from button click handler not working

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, popupmenu

```
// CMFCApplication1Dlg dialog
CMFCApplication1Dlg::CMFCApplication1Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication1Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication1Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CMFCApplication1Dlg message handlers
BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
// the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    //Simulating the similar code as product
    CFrameWnd *pFrame = GetParentFrame();
    CMenu popup;
    popup.CreatePopupMenu();

    LPCWSTR pszMenuItem2 = L"Korean with wchar_t: 기존 운";
    AppendMenuW(popup.m_hMenu, MF_STRING, 1, pszMenuItem2);

    TCHAR* pszMenuItem3 = "|| Korean without wchar_t: 또는 차량 삽입";
    AppendMenu(popup.m_hMenu, MF_STRING, 2, pszMenuItem3);

    UINT nCmd = popup.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD,
                                    14, 20, pFrame, 0);
}
```

I have written above piece of code to generate popup menu in the screen on button click but it doesn't show any menu at all? Am I missing something?

As you asked here is the complete code. Actually I have placed one static button through GUI and on button click trying to generate the popup menu.

These button is not created dynamically. Also, the entire code here is generated by wizard except the last portion of the code about the button click.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in your event handler that displays the menu and traced the progress. We don't know what event / message you have this code in.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to MFC. I am able to debug but not sure where to trace the progress on menu. It's not showing anything on CMenu object(popup). Can you help me where can we check that?

Comment: Where have you put this code?

Comment: CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()

Comment: Can't you show us the complete code? How did you create this button handler? Do you have teh associates MESSAGE_MAP entry? If you have it set up properly you should be able to put a breakpoint in your button handler and then run it in debug mode with F5.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, sorry, I updated the code in the post. Please check

Comment: Good. As I mentioned before, place a breakpoint inside that handler and debug it. If you do not know how to do that then please learn about debugging. You need to see if that handle you are using is NULL. I say this because you are using a dialog application and I have never used GetParentFrame (which is for single/multi document interface apps). I normally use GetSafeHWnd().

Comment: Thank you @AndrewTruckle. You are right. Handle was issue. If I use GetSafeHWnd, It shows the popup menu. Thanks once again

Comment: You are welcome. I would have provided an answer but you beat me to it. 

Comment: Still the credit goes to you :)

Comment: The actual problem I was facing that, in my sample project it displays the text string of popup menu having Korean character (기존 운) but with the same code in my company project, it replaces all the Korean character to '?'(question mark) and displays ('???').

When I get the text string of menu, it is altered to '?' after TrackPopupMenu() call

Comment: That is a new question. More than likely you have to make sure your actual RC file is Unicode encoded. Not on pc right now. But it is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the handle, if I use the right API to get the handle, it shows the popup menu.
Here is the updated code.

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    //Simulating the similar code as product
    HWND wnd= GetSafeHwnd();//<---- this had to change  
    CMenu popup;
    popup.CreatePopupMenu();

    LPCWSTR pszMenuItem2 = L"Korean with wchar_t: 기존 운";
    AppendMenuW(popup.m_hMenu, MF_STRING, 1, pszMenuItem2);

    TCHAR* pszMenuItem3 = "|| Korean without wchar_t: 또는 차량 삽입";
    AppendMenu(popup.m_hMenu, MF_STRING, 2, pszMenuItem3);

    UINT nCmd = popup.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD,
                                    14, 20, CWnd::FromHandle(wnd)/*need this api to get the CWnd from HWND*/, 0);
```

Comment: Instead of `CWnd::FromHandle(wnd)` you could have just used `this`.

Comment: @MarkRansom The actual problem I was facing that, in my sample project it displays the text string of popup menu having Korean character (기존 운) but with the same code in my company project, it replaces all the Korean character to '?'(question mark) and displays ('???'). When I get the text string of menu, it is altered to '?' after TrackPopupMenu() call

Comment: That probably means your company project is built in Ansi mode rather than Unicode mode.  Although if changing the parent window changes things, that implies a mixed mode which is very hard to get without going through special contortions.